# Joomla: Is there a querystring parameter that can remove a pages theme?

Tags: joomla

We've got a joomla website and are now in the process of developing a [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) application to complement it.

Since our website is in joomla, I don't want to have to write any PHP to extract page data separate from the main site.

Is there any type of querystring parameter that can disable the theme?

> IE:
>   http://example.com/about-us?show-theme=false

If this is not possible, is there any other option to achieve similar results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index2.php is depreciated and is no longer supported in new versions of Joomla. What you are looking for is ?tmpl=component. You can add that to any Joomla URL and it will only display what you have coded in the /templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/component.php file. The default loads just the component output, but you can customize it to do what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do I get your question right: you want to extract the content from the page, without menu and so on? 2 possibilities, then:

- Extract it from the concerning **RSS feed** (of the front page, of a category ... if you need more options you can install an component such as [Total RSS](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/rss-syndicate/6526)
- Use **index2.php**: [example site](http://www.lancasterhistory.org/index2.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=61) (This doesn't seem to work if you use URL Rewriting as in your example URL.)

Answer (score 0):

you can add format=raw in the URL. This will only output the content of the component and not the template.

This is used to show printable pages.
You may have to create a view.raw.php file along with the view.html.php